# Website is smaller when uploaded to ftp

Tags: html, css, layout, ftp, scale

I've created a website using only html & css.
My problem now is that when I uploaded all of my files to my ftp-server (using filezilla), everything seems to scaled down. Which messes up my layout significantly. The font size is scaled down aswel.
I thought using a normalize would surpass this issue, apparently not.

Any tips?

Cheers!

Comment: This isn't enough information to provide a serious answer, but do check your browser's zoom setting, which is often stored on a per-domain basis. Make sure it's 100% (or whatever the "neutral" position is) on both domains

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suitable for webmastering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that you were zoomed in too far when you were offline (before uploading to ftp) or that you you're zoomed out now that has been uploaded to the FTP.

Press CNTRL+0 or Commaned+0 to reset your browser to the default zoom.

Comment: this fixed it, feel kinda stupid for asking a question with such a simple answer to it... So I shouldn't be concerned for other people opening my URL and being zoomed out aswel? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably zoomed out in your browser.  Your browser will typically remember your zoom settings for a different hostname.

FTP has absolutely nothing to do with this... you're just transferring files.  FTP doesn't know or care about what those files are, or their contents (outside of ASCII or Binary transfer modes).